# Extract unique listo of fields from maching document

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am new to Lucene, so maybe i have missunderstood something about how it works.

I have indexed few hundred thousand documents with many string field. For example suppose we have 5 string field (named A,B,C,D,E) and the first 3 are indexed (A,B,C) leaving the last two unindexed, only included into the document (i mean D,E). Values in each field may be duplicate, for example assume that the field A is used to store names, and the name 'Richard' appear many times.

When i apply a query i looking for each term in each field, now for example, suppose i get 3K documents that match my query.

Is it possible to get a list of unique values (distinct) of each fields without scan and group the result? I am particularly interested into this because i apply a limit to the documents i actually read, but i would like to get a complete list of unique values in each fields (even the documents i dont' read) of the matching documents.

If this is possibile, can i apply this logic even for unindexed fields (D,E) ?

Comment: The Distinct class is done in two steps.  A hash is created for every obj ect(ouput is an integer).  When every object has a unique has you have a distinct set.  When two object have the same has the actual object has to be compared to determine unique values because there is a very small possibility in the c# hash class the two different objects can have to same hash output.

Comment: @jdweng probably i missunderstand something, but i don't want to implement a distinct search over a collection of in-mermory objects. I would apply the equivalent of SQL "select distinct my_field from documents where query_cond" that will fetch only the distinct list from Lucene, without the need to read each document

Comment: I never said SEARCH.  Do do a Distinct algorithm you have to compare every item against every other item which take (N^2)/2.  Doing a Hash can reduce time because you can sort the hash in linear time.  Then only do additional comparisons on the items that have duplicate hash values.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, but is this somewhat related to my question about lucene.net? If yes how? Is not clear to me

Comment: @jdweng I have re-read your comment and is not only out of topic, but also wrong. "Distinct algorithm" as you call it may be also implemented on sorted list and will take "only" nlog(n). So yes hash tables are good technology (my preferred one for such thing) but that said I am still to the starting point when I have to use a built in functionality of Lucerne.net to achieve this

Comment: @jdweng I reported you then, I report you again now. Data structures are OT here, I just asked how to use Lucene.Net API to achieve this goal. Now if you would talk about data structures (OT) i answer you that implementing distinct algorithm on unsorted list will take nlogn if you choose sorting approach. If you use an hash table it will cost only n ( n*o(1) = n ). But all that said this is pretty irrelevant when I ask how to achieve this through use of Lucene.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing the search, it will return to you all the documents that have the query conditions. On that result you can do a highlight (which will slow the process), but you can do something like pagination to return the result in pages if you want.

In the highligher you have many methods you can use (depending on what version of Lucene you are using; I am talking here about the last version 4.8.0) like `GetBestTextFragments()` which takes a parameter called `maxNumberFragments`. If you set that parameter to 1 then it will return only one value from that particular field even if there might be multiple values that match the query.

I am not sure if that answers your question, but I hope it helps. Regarding the unindexed fields, I dont think you can do that (although I have never tried it).